# "package libmono-security4.0-cil is not ready for configuration" how to make it ready?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm getting this error

```
New software can't be installed, because there is a problem 
with the software currently installed. Do you want to 
repair this problem now?
```

And other than this error message popup has only two button. "cancel and "Repair"

And when I click repair, same pop up comes back.

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS

```
jitendra@jitendra-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cli-common libmono-corlib4.5-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
  libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libthunarx-2-0
  libtumbler-1-0 mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mono-runtime-common
  mono-runtime-sgen thunar-data tumbler tumbler-common xfdesktop4-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/110 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libmono-security4.0-cil (--configure):
 package libmono-security4.0-cil is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

```
jitendra@jitendra-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cli-common libmono-corlib4.5-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
  libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libthunarx-2-0
  libtumbler-1-0 mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mono-runtime-common
  mono-runtime-sgen thunar-data tumbler tumbler-common xfdesktop4-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 110 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ubuntu.uhost.hk/ trusty/main libmono-security4.0-cil all 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1 [110 kB]
Fetched 110 kB in 1s (86.9 kB/s)                
dpkg: error processing package libmono-security4.0-cil (--configure):
 package libmono-security4.0-cil is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the partially installed package `libmono-security4.0-cil` and then fix the dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get purge libmono-security4.0-cil
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.getting this http://pastebin.com/80d7RAxd

Comment: not yet. this is output http://pastebin.com/80d7RAxd

Comment: now try this command `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libmono-security4.0-cil`. Then run `sudo apt-get install -f`